# How to append python dictionary to text file

Tags: python

I tried the following the code

```
import json
final_key = ["letters", "words", "score"]
final_list = []
letters_1=['U', 'I', 'J', 'T', 'D', 'F', 'S', 'H', 'J']
final_list.append(letters_1)
word=['U', 'T', 'S']
final_list.append(word)
score = 3
final_list.append(score)
res = {}
for key in final_key:
    for value in final_list:
        res[key] = value
        final_list.remove(value)
        break
with open('log.txt', 'w') as convert_file:
     convert_file.write(json.dumps(res))
```

Then I got the following output

```
{"letters": ["U", "I", "J", "T", "D", "F", "S", "H", "J"], "words": ["U", "T", "S"], "score": 3}
```

After that creation, I need to append another dictionary to the above-created text. Ro achieve that I tried following code

```
final_list_1=[]
letters_2=['A', 'P', 'J', 'P', 'F', 'F', 'L', 'H', 'P']
final_list_1.append(letters_2)
word_1=['L', 'V', 'S','G']
final_list_1.append(word_1)
score_1 = 10
final_list_1.append(score_1)
res_1 = {}
for key in final_key:
    for value in final_list_1:
        res_1[key] = value
        final_list_1.remove(value)
        break
with open('log.txt', 'a') as convert_file:
     convert_file.write(json.dumps(res_1))
```

My output was

```
{"letters": ["U", "I", "J", "T", "D", "F", "S", "H", "J"], "words": ["U", "T", "S"], "score": 3}
{"letters": ["A", "P", "J", "P", "F", "F", "L", "H", "P"], "words": ["L", "V", "S", "G"], "score": 10}
```

But I need the following kind of output

```
[
{"letters": ["U", "I", "J", "T", "D", "F", "S", "H", "J"], "words": ["U", "T", "S"], "score": 3},

{"letters": ["A", "P", "J", "P", "F", "F", "L", "H", "P"], "words": ["L", "V", "S", "G"], "score": 10}
]
```

What kind of change does the code have to make for this?

Comment: Append your `res` and `res_1` into a list, and `json.dumps(...)` *that list*

Comment: You have to read the file and overwrite it completely because you can't insert anything into an existing file, only overwrite and append.

Comment: just for the record... it is not a good idea to do `final_list_1.remove(value)` while you are iterating over final_list_1.

Comment: JSON is not an appendable format.  What you currently have is [JSON Lines](https://jsonlines.org/) format where each *line* is a complete JSON object, and is better suited for appending.

Comment: I did some thing and attached as answer but also there is some problem

Answer (score 2):

One way is to write the list of the dictionary elements to the file at the end

```
with open('log.txt', 'w') as convert_file:
    conver_file.write(json.dumps([res, res_1]))
```

---

**Edit**: As OP wants to append dictionary elements every time its created, the steps are as follows:

At the beginning of the code, insert an empty list into the file

```
with open('log.txt', 'w') as convert_file:
    convert_file.write(json.dumps([]))
```

While appending a dictionary, remove the last square bracket, append the dictionary and then add the bracket again

```
with open('log.txt', 'rb+') as convert_file:
    convert_file.seek(-1, 2)
    convert_file.truncate()

with open('log.txt', 'a') as convert_file:
    convert_file.write(json.dumps(res))
    convert_file.write(']')
```

Using `rb+` because it opens the file in binary format and also allows to edit the contents in the file

Comment: This one can use when we write two dictionaries at the same time. But I want to append a second dictionary when 1st one already created @Geeky Quentin

Comment: As you can append or write to a file a `string` only, you have to keep adding the `dict` elements to a different list and then overwrite the content everytime

Comment: I've edited as you said, in this case, use a function to write to the file as writing code to write to the file everytime a new dict is created becomes tidious

Comment: No, actually again that is not my task. The thing is I want to create the first list. That's ok.. Then think every output will clear, so there is only an available text file (no any variable, no any code, no any outputs). Now I create a second dictionary and then I want to append to text file @Geeky Quentin

Comment: Can you check my answer below @Geeky Quentin

Answer (score 0):

Actually you already got the solution. Just need to add `json.loads(lines[0])` in the final line to get rid of the escape character `\` :

```
with open('log.txt', 'w') as convert_file:
    convert_file.write(json.dumps([json.loads(lines[0]), res_1]))
```

Edit: Here's the full solution (mostly from OP):

```
import json
final_key = ["letters", "words", "score"]
final_list = []
letters_1=['U', 'I', 'J', 'T', 'D', 'F', 'S', 'H', 'J']
final_list.append(letters_1)
word=['U', 'T', 'S']
final_list.append(word)
score = 3
final_list.append(score)
res = {}
for key in final_key:
    for value in final_list:
        res[key] = value
        final_list.remove(value)
        break
with open('log.txt', 'w') as convert_file:
     convert_file.write(json.dumps(res))

final_list_1=[]
letters_2=['A', 'P', 'J', 'P', 'F', 'F', 'L', 'H', 'P']
final_list_1.append(letters_2)
word_1=['L', 'V', 'S','G']
final_list_1.append(word_1)
score_1 = 10
final_list_1.append(score_1)
res_1 = {}
for key in final_key:
    for value in final_list_1:
        res_1[key] = value
        final_list_1.remove(value)
        break
with open('log.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
with open('log.txt', 'w') as convert_file:
    convert_file.write(json.dumps([json.loads(lines[0]), res_1]))
```

Output `log.txt`

```
[
{"letters": ["U", "I", "J", "T", "D", "F", "S", "H", "J"], "words": ["U", "T", "S"], "score": 3}, 
{"letters": ["A", "P", "J", "P", "F", "F", "L", "H", "P"], "words": ["L", "V", "S", "G"], "score": 10}
]
```

Comment: Where did the `lines[0]` come from? Also once you *listify* `res` and `res_1`, the next time you want to write the updated list, you are writing to the file, the *list* of *list of res, res_1* and *res_2*

Comment: hi @GeekyQuentin, i've appended the full solution above, it's mostly from the OP, only the final line is edited.